# How do I filter jquery datatable based on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using jquery dataTable to display employees collection to display employee Id, Employee Name , depart Name , Employee designation.

I can see DataTable, Now I have added Department name Drop Down above Jquery DataTable Now i have to filter employees Grid based on value selected in above dropdown value.

How To do this ??

I have added jquery DataTable for Employees and Its working ,now want to filter records based on value selected in Dropdown above it, grid should change as per change in dropdown.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        //$('#datatable').dataTable({
        //    //'scrollY': 100
        //});

        DrawDatatable();

    });
```

i want to refresh grid on change of drop down placed above grid

Comment: Please provide some more context about the actual data source, are you loading data through ajax or is statically loaded, also please put some effort into trying to solve the problem as well. Datatables.net has a good enough manual and a full API reference as well. I believe that if you just looked at their api examples, they are already doing this [link](https://www.datatables.net/manual/api#Example---column-filter). If this doesn't solve your problem, then please reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are fetching data through ajax in your datatable. If that's the case you can achieve it by passing parameter in your url. **Example :**

```
data_list = $("#datatable").dataTable({
   // 
});

$(".opt").change(function () {
   data_list.fnReloadAjax("(..your base url..)?startDate=" + $('.opt').val());
   data_list.fnClearTable(0);
   data_list.fnDraw();
});
```